# function.file-get-contents failed to open stream : http request failed

Tags: php

I am having a php file that gets the contents from a URL, i am getting the failure message 'Warning: file_get_contents(http://cc.frifon.net/_dosmssend) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\xampp\htdocs\SMS\cuba.php on line 24
bool(false)'

Here is my code:

```
        <?php

            $url = 'http://cc.frifon.net/_dosmssend';
            $data = array('sip' => '60146600472', 'uuid' => 
           '503AEE00-FB59-4868-B293-0FA4FFC17ACB', 'pwd' => '233443959918', 
           'key' => 'key', 'to' => 'to', 'message' => 'message' );

           // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
           $options = array(
           'http' => array(
           'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
           'method'  => 'POST',
           'content' => http_build_query($data),
           ),
           );
           $context  = stream_context_create($options);
           $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

           var_dump($result);

           ?>
```

Comment: The API is not functional anymore.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you provided a URL that doesn't exist

```
http://cc.frifon.net/_dosmssend
```

Returns a **404**